# Find number of fans in a laptop

Tags: laptop, temperature, fan

My laptop is always hot and CPU temp is about 80°C.

I guess one of laptop fans is corrupted and another one spins in high RPM, because I hear the sound of fan speed which it is most of time is high.

How can I find number of fans in my laptop (VAIO F13 HFX, Core i7) and each fan's speed?

I am on fedora 18 , but i had same problem in ubuntu 12.10 and 12.04

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @schaiba i edit the question!

Comment: I don't believe finding out the speed of the fans will help you. We'd rather find out how to make said fans be quieter. First please look if you have some BIOS settings regarding fan speed and if so, adjust them accordingly. Then, a good cleanup of the laptop wouldn't hurt, seeing that it is already a few years old.

Comment: in 2 or 3 month ago the default temp was about 50~55,

but now, it never comes lower than 70!

Comment: ..which makes me repeat that you should clean your laptop thoroughly.

Comment: schaiba's probably right; if the laptop is more than a few years old or gets used alot and left on in a dusty environment, it's now no longer getting ventilated properly because the vents inside are plugged.  I've taken more than one laptop apart and found what is essentially a shag carpet *insulating* the chamber around the CPU.  If so, your next stage will be: shuts down 15 minutes after you turn it on due to overheating. http://www.irisvista.com/tech/laptops/ToshibaP15/heatsink_removal/big/Toshiba-SatelliteP15-heatsink-06.jpg

Comment: The definitive answer to your specific number of fans question would best be answered by the vendor site concerning this computer.

Comment: yes, Probably dirty, but I just use laptop on the desk!

Comment: Even if you only use the laptop on the desk, fans will eventually get dirty.

Comment: i opened the RAM cover and know the Temp is about 60 C.

Answer (score 1):

lmsensors should do the trick?

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lm_sensors

Comment: yes i test the lmsensors but there isn't any info about fan and fanspeed in the resault of `sensors` command

Answer (score 0):

Check out the i8kUtils package. It is commonly put into conky (a cool monitoring app that can sit on your desktop.)

Comment: thanks ,but I don't want to set up conky!

Comment: You can still use tools from the i8kUtils package from the command line.

Comment: i searched but although my laptop hasn't `pwm-copable sensor modules`.

Answer (score 0):

dmidecode should give you a view into your BIOS from the OS, usually includes fan and cooling data.